# Validación de número decimal( letras y negativos )

Tags: javascript, jquery

No soy muy bueno con las expresiones regulares y me están pidiendo que valide que el sueldo solo acepte decimales positivos.

Tengo para números enteros positvos esta función.

```
    function validarEnteroPositivo(elemento){ 
    tmp = $(elemento), valor = parseInt(Math.round(tmp.val()));
    (isNaN(valor) || valor < 1) ? tmp.val("") : tmp.val(""); tmp.val(valor);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es exactamente el problema que tienes? ¿No te funciona? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: Cambia la sentencia `parseInt` por `parseFloat` y elimina el `Math.round`.

Comment: esta funcion es para enteros y necesito para decimales y que no se pueda escribir negativos

Comment: si deja veo para que es math round gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una función que valida perfectamente tu requerimiento y que devuelve `true` o `false` es la que sigue:

```
function validarPositivo(elemento) {
  return (parseFloat(elemento.split(" ").join("").split(",").join("") || 0) > 0;
}
```

Esta función incluso permite añadir espacios o comas (separadores de miles) y aun así validar que sea un número.

Comment: La función no es legible y es inóptima: separa por espacios y luego los vuelve a unir con caracteres vacíos, después hace lo mismo con las comas. No sería mas fácil, legible y óptimo usar la función `replace` de javascript? Además lo del separador de miles no es así, con poner `validarPositivo("1,200.12,2")` ya cae en bugs